# Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError for AdSense/Publisher related metrics

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, adsense, google-api-dotnet-client

Since yesterday, we have trouble getting data from the Analytics API for AdSense related metrics (*ga:adsensePageImpressions, ga:adsenseAdsViewed, ga:adsenseCoverage etc.*). Other metric like *ga:sessions* are still working.

Is this some permission problem?

From the main account, I can log into Analytics, and I do see current AdSense (Publisher) data.

.NET, Google.Apis.Analytics.V3 1.20.0.642 (up to date), Google.Apis.AnalyticsReporting.v4 1.20.0.698.
Tried with V3 and V4, same error.

We are using a service account that has permission to access Analytics data.
I’ve checked AdSense, Analytics, and API Management settings, but cannot find anything related.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the problem? What is the error you are getting in API response?

Comment: _No such dimension(s): ga:adsenseAdsViewed, No such metric(s): ga:adsenseECPM_ - Error 400 Invalid Parameter

Comment: It says requires integration with AdSense.

Comment: Also reported here: https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=1174

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they have updated Analytics API and it's no longer possible to call API with AdSense/Publisher metrics for Analytics properties that do not have linked AdSense account.

Unfortunately, in cases where there are hundreds of sites and where some of the sites have AdSense, and other do not, you have to create different API calls for those two groups.