# Google Analytics API v3 : Unknown metric(s): ga:adsenseAdsViewed, ga:adsenseAdsClicks, ga:adsenseRevenue, ga:adsenseAdUnitsViewed

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

It seems that something has changed last thursday/friday with the following metrics : ga:adsenseAdsViewed, ga:adsenseAdsClicks, ga:adsenseRevenue, ga:adsenseAdUnitsViewed

I was able to pull these metrics before and since a while and I'm no longer able to have these metrics since last friday.

I'm hit by : *Unknown metric(s): ga:adsenseAdsViewed, ga:adsenseAdsClicks, ga:adsenseRevenue, ga:adsenseAdUnitsViewed*

I went to the API change logs, no changes since 2016-10-12. These metrics also are still showing available in the documentation.

In the past, this already happened and a quick retry fixed the issue - but this is no longer the case right now.

Does someone has already got the same issue? Are these field removed? Something else?

Thank you a lot for any feedback

Comment: Similar question.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41523956/google-apis-requests-requesterror-for-adsense-publisher-related-metrics

Comment: Also reported here: https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=1174

Comment: Please up vote and accept the Answer below so that we can close the duplicate question @Pierre-LucSoucy pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in the latest release, see [changelog](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/changelog) for details.

### AdSense dimensions and metrics

This release fixes an issue which started on 1/7/2017 in which querying for [AdSense dimensions and metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=adsense)
  would return an `Unknown Metric` error for non-AdSense linked views.

#### Coming changes

On or after 1/31/2017 non-AdSense linked views will be restricted from
  querying for AdSense dimensions and metrics. Querying for these dimensions
  and metrics with a non-AdSense linked views will result in an error.

#### Update your code

If possible link the views with the AdSense account when needed otherwise you should check the [error messages](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/errors) and have your client respond accordingly.